# Content:author Relationship Not Showing Fields for Comments View

Tags: views, comments

I have created a view to show a nodes comments in a block.

Authors on my site have different roles, and they can create a single business page. On that page, other users can leave comments.

For site authors that have a "**Free Listing**" role, I want to hide the ability for other users to post comments.

To do this, I have added a view to display comments, then added a relationship for **Comment:Content**, then a relationship for **Content:Author**.

In my previous experience, this should give me a field **(Content)Author:Role** to filter results by. Instead, I get no additional fields, just the standard Content:Author ID field, which then tells me..."If you need more fields than the uid add the content: author relationship", I have!!!

Have I uncovered a bug? Or am I missing something?

[image]

[image]

Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to filter for a *User* fields if I understand correctly (i.e. you want to display only comments on the current node when the node author has a certain role).

Select *User: Roles* as the filter and make sure the **Relationship** select box is set to the identifier for *Content: Author*. That will let you filter the comments by the node author's role.

Comment: Ah! I am a moron! That was staring me right in the face, but I just assumed it was for the role of the comment author. Thanks!